# How to use Tomcat CSRF protection filter with session invalidation in Java

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I've read the Tomcat CSRF protection fileter documentation and to my understanding the entry point must be pages that do not perform a security function.

I understand that when used any of the entry points are part of the nonce in the current session.

However as per the OWASP top 10 recommendations, I'm invalidating the session when a user logs in and generating a new session.

The issue I find is that when this is done, if a user clicks on a link that is only available once logged in, for example change password, which does not form part of the entry points a 403 is returned, due to the new session.

If the user clicks on one of the entry point urls first, they can then click on the change password link and access the page because a new nonce has been created and the change password link will be covered by this, but if the welcome page has other links that the user needs to use they cannot use the back button and click on the link(s) then as the nonce is not the same.

My question is how to handle the fact that when the new session is created the change password page will not be accessible without first clicking on one of the entry point urls.

I have looked at encoding the url, but it maybe my code is not written to handle this as correctly also I'm using JSTL due to its escaping properties to help prevent XSS and I can't seem to find a way to encode the urls with this.

Can anyone offer some advice or option as what would be best to do.

If it will help I'm including the login section of my controller servlet, which is reached via a login form post method.

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
String url = "";
// Register a new user
if (requestURI.endsWith("/subscribeToSite")) {
    url = subscribeToSite(request, response);
}
// Login
if(requestURI.endsWith("/logInToSite")){
    url = logInToSite(request, response);
}
  //try to  login
User user = UserDB.loginUser(mPNum, upwd);
if(user==null){
    url = "/loginerror.jsp";
}else{
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       session.invalidate();
       session=request.getSession(true);
       session.setAttribute("loggedUsrID", user.getUserID());
       session.setAttribute("loggedUsrFName", user.getFName());
       url="/schedule/welcome.jsp";
}      
return url;
}//EO user login
```

Comment: Any one got an idea?

Comment: OK I'm forwarding all my requests and found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530341/not-able-to-authenticate-post-request-for-csrf-token-with-tomcat

But adding the dispatcher does not fix the issue, the only way I can get this to work is to not invalidate the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK worked around this by invalidating the session when logging in. Then creating the token off another page that is accessible only through the landing page.